# Waiting until the desired condition is met in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the below program, I want to wait until the output of the `status` variable is "True" and if the `status` variable is
"True", I want to return the `status` variable's output.

```py
import subprocess

class MyLibrary(object):

    def execute(self, cmd):
        result = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        out, err = result.communicate()
        return str(out)

    def list(self):
        command = ["<application_command>", "list"]
        status = self.execute(command).__contains__("running")
        <<How to achieve my condition??>>
        return status

test = MyLibrary()
test.list()
```

Comment: [The `while` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement)

Comment: @Tomerikoo, Thanks. Yeah I am aware it should be while statement, but not sure how to use it for my particular scenario.

Comment: Side-note: `status = self.execute(command).__contains__("running")` should really be `status = "running" in self.execute(command)`. Both do the same thing, but the latter uses the normal, idiomatic Python syntax instead of calling the magic method directly (which is actually slower than using the syntax-based approach).

Comment: A while loop without a sleep will max out your CPU for no good reason. Is there any reason you can't use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) instead of `Popen`?

Comment: @Multihunter: `subprocess.run` is basically just a wrapper for `Popen`; the OP is using `communicate` immediately, so for all practical purposes the end result is the same.

Comment: @Multihunter, Thanks for the comment. yeah, I need to include a timeout which I am checking. Also, I used subprocess.popen, because it has .communicate() that reads the output and I used that output to assert in my second method. **Is it possible to achieve the same in subprocess.run()?**

Comment: @ShadowRanger Sorry, there was an assumption that I was asking about; I should have been clearer. OP, if you started the execution that you are polling yourself with `subprocess.Popen` then you could consider refactoring to instead use `subprocess.run` on that execution instead of doing any polling at all. But maybe that's not applicable here.

Comment: Yes, if you're using python 3.7+, you can use `subprocess.run([...], capture_output=True, encoding='utf-8')` to run a command, wait for it to end, and then read the stdout, but as ShadowRanger points out, it's basically what you are doing already with `Popen` and `.communicate()`, so it's not really important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this<sup>1</sup>:

```
import time
def list(self):
    command = ["<application_command>", "list"]
    status = False
    start = time.time()
    while True: # while status is false
        status = "running" in self.execute(command)
        if ((time.time() - start) >= 60) and status:
            return
        if status: # if the status is true
            return status
        else:
            continue
```

<sub>1: from the [ShadowRanger's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65220567/waiting-until-the-desired-condition-is-met-in-python/65228481#comment115317203_65228287)</sub>

Comment: thanks @ppwater. How do I include timeout in the above loop? because if the status is not running, this will run for ever. I want to exit the loop after a minute.

Comment: You can use [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) to not hammer your CPU, and you can use [`start = time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) to record the time you start polling, and measure how long it's been with `time.time() - start`. If you don't want to do it yourself, there's always a tiny library: https://github.com/justiniso/polling.

Comment: @iamstuck Oh, just saw your comment. I'll post that.

Comment: @ppwater, I updated it. Guess, it is write way of doing it. thanks indeed.

Comment: @ppwater, I need both the boolean (True or False) from the variable "status". In case, if  "running" pattern is not found even after 60 sec, I need the "status" as False, and if it is found then "status" as True. So, my question here, is it not better to have a "(time.time() - start) >= 60" as a OR condition as part of line "if status:" [like this -- if status or (time.time() - start) >= 60:], so that I will get both the boolean from the "status" based on its value.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I myself found the answer. It is working fine.

```
def list(self):
    command = ["<application_command>", "list"]
    status = False
    while status is not True:
        status = self.execute(command).__contains__("running")
        if status is True:
            return status
        else:
            continue
```

Hope this writing style is fine. If not, request your comments.

**Updated the program with timeout option as well**:

```
import subprocess
import time

class MyLibrary(object):
    def execute(self, cmd):
        result = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        out, err = result.communicate()
        return str(out)

    def list(self):
        command = ["<application command>", "list"]
        return self.execute(command)

    def check(self):
        timeout = time.time() + 60
        status = False
        while not status:  # while status is false
            status = "running" in self.list()
            if status or time.time() > timeout:  # if the status is true
                return status
            else:
                continue
```

Comment: Adding to idiomatic note from question, testing `is (not) True` is not necessary and it's [considered bad style in the Python style guide, PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations). Use `while not status:` and `if status:`, don't compare to `True` at all.